# How to trace Knapsack problem using greedy algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, greedy, knapsack-problem

The question is how to trace a Knapsack problem with greedy algorithm using the following information?

```
P=[10,7,12,13,6,20]
W=[3,2,4,3,13,8]
M=15
n=6
```

I'd appreciate it if some one could help me understand this or point me to the right direction.

Comment: What are P, W, M and n? What does it mean to 'trace a Knapsack problem'?

Comment: I mean step by step, perform the algorithm and check the outputs.

Comment: Also P is price of the items, W is the weights of them, M is the maximum amount the knapsack can contain. and n is the number of items.

Comment: And which item will the greedy algorithm choose first? Do you have some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it's 'fractional knapsack' (i.e. you can take fractions of the items) then it's easy:

The items are (as price, weight pairs) [(10, 3), (7, 2), (12, 4), (13, 3), (6, 13), (20, 8)]

Intuitively, you'll want to get an item first which will provide more price with less weight. So, let's sort the items by their price to weight ratio:

[(13, 3), (7, 2), (10, 3), (12, 4), (20, 8), (6, 13)]

Now, until you run out of capacity or an item, take the most valuable item as much as you can.

```
0. cap = 15, price = 0
1. Take (13, 3): cap = 12, price = 13
2. Take (7, 2): cap = 10, price = 20
3. Take (10, 3): cap = 7, price = 30
4. Take (12, 4): cap = 3, price = 42
5. Take (20, 8): cap = 0, price = 49.5
   [in this step, you have capacity to take 3 units, so take 3 units of the 5th item, the price of which is 3*20/8]
```

If you cannot take fractional items, then such a greedy approach may not give you the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the first step, that is, 1. Take (13, 3): cap = 12, price = 15, 
since 3 items are added, so the price will be 13*3=39... It proceeds in the same manner. When 2 more are added then 7*2=14 is added. So the cost in step 2 will be 39+14=53.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int r;
int* sort(int list[],int n)
    {

        int temp;
        bool swap =true;
        int i;
        while(swap)
        {
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)

                {
                if(list[i]>list[j])
                    {
                    temp=list[j];
                    list[j]=list[i];
                    list[i]=temp;
                    swap= true;
                    }else
                        {
                        swap= false;
                        }

                }
            }
        }
        return (list);

    }
int* knapsack(int list[],int k)
{
    const int n=6;
    int c=0;

    int ks[n];
    int sum=0;
    int u;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
    sum=sum+list[i];
        if(sum<=k)
        {
            u=list[i];
            ks[i]=u;
            list[i]=i+1;
            c++;
            //cout<<"Index number in sorted list : "<<i+1<<" "<<endl;
        }
    }

    r=c;
    return (list);

}

int main() 
{
    double difference1,difference2;
    clock_t start,end;   
    const int m=5;
    int list[m]={8,6,7,4,9};
    cout<<"Your list of sizes of parcel : ";
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cout<<list[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    start = clock();

    int* x=sort(list,m);  //call to sorting function to sort the list in increasing size order.

    end = clock();
    difference1=((start-end)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout<<"Sorted list of sizes of parcel : ";
    for (int j = 0; j <m; j++) 
    {cout<<x[j]<<" ";}

    cout<<endl<<endl;
    111
    int k=24;   //Size of sack

    start = clock();

    int* g= knapsack(list,k); //call to knapsack function

    end = clock();
    difference2=((start-end)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        cout<<"Indexes taken from sorted list : ";
                for(int l=0;l<r;l++)
                {
                cout<<g[l]<<" ";
                }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Time elapsed : "<<(difference1+difference2)<<endl<<endl;

}
```